# Ajax Mess trying to create SetInterval functions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, intervals

Okay, I asked a question earlier but I've run into a whole new problem. I have a PHP array in a PHP script server side. I am trying to write a Client side Ajax script to repoll the PHP script for new data and update the statistics displayed on the page.

Heres the Ajax that im sure im not doing right:

```
setInterval(function(getLatestInfo) 
{  
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'script.php',
    data: 'id=data',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(getLatestInfo){
    $.getJSON(script.php, function(getLatestInfo){
    var result_array = JSON.parse(result);
    });
    $('#bit_rate').html(result_array[4]);
    $('#listeners').html(result_array[5]);
    $('#current_song').html(result_array[9]);
                });
            });
            }, 10000);//time in milliseconds
```

And here is the PHP:

```
            <?php 
            Function getLatestInfo() {

$SERVER = 'http://chillstep.info:1984'; 
$STATS_FILE = '/status.xsl?mount=/test.mp3'; 
$LASTFM_API= '00000000000000000'; 

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$SERVER.$STATS_FILE); 

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 

$output = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch); 

$dp = array(); 

$search_for = "<td\s[^>]*class=\"streamdata\">(.*)<\/td>"; 
$search_td = array('<td class="streamdata">','</td>'); 

if(preg_match_all("/$search_for/siU",$output,$matches)) { 
   foreach($matches[0] as $match) { 
      $to_push = str_replace($search_td,'',$match); 
      $to_push = trim($to_push); 
      array_push($dp,$to_push); 
   } 
} 

$x = explode(" - ",$dp[9]); 

echo json_encode($dp);
            }
 ?>
```

In short, I need this ajax script to update and pull the PHP variable $dp, which is an array, parse it out, and create HTML usable string variables. And repeat the process every 10 seconds.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish here. Why not query  the chillstep server directly? jQuery is quite capable of parsing XML:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: But be careful of cross browser AJAX calls when using the parseXML method

Comment: Partially because im just starting with AJAX and didn't know we could do that. Also, the HTTPrequests sends back everything all at once and I'm just using the PHP to parse it all out into useful bits. Id like to avoid PHP all together if its possible, I just have no idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use setInterval in this instance. In the success callback call the original function again. Also you are calling getJSON in the success callback of the ajax call - this is duplicating calls.

For example

```
function getlatest()
{
  $.ajax({
  //rest of ajax param
  success : function(results){
    var resultarray = $.parseJSON(results);
    $('#bit_rate').html(result_array[4]);
    $('#listeners').html(result_array[5]);
    $('#current_song').html(result_array[9]);
    getlatest();
  }
  });
}
```